# load file within a jar

Tags: java, jar

I need to package a configuration file within a jar.  the configuration file is under the root of the jar file.
However I got the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
>     at java.io.File.(Unknown Source)

```
File url = new File(MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("my.conf").toURI());
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should use [`getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) instead. If the file is embedded in your JAR the URI is most likely bundle:// URI

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("my.conf");
```

Answer (score 7):

Why do you need a file? IF you need to read the config use

```
Class.getResourceAsStream("/my.conf");
```

This will need only to be the file in the one folder with the root of your package( the same as in the root of the jar)

Answer (score 4):

The file should be in the same package as the MyClass. I just realized you are creating a File object. Instead try using getResourceAsStream(). This is the right way if you want to read the contents from a classpath resource. Here [is the example](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/getresourceasstream.html).

Comment: correction: the file was found, but since it's inside a jar, i got uri is not hierarchical error

Comment: Following error should be shown "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical"