# Leading backslash in path names in java

Tags: java, ant, path, apache-commons

So, I am trying to code a regular Java application which reads the current revision from a file which is updated by ANT during compile time. When run on my dev machine (Eclipse 3.5.2 on Ubuntu 11.04) with either the OpenJDK or SunJDK, it throws a `FileNotFoundException`. Adding or removing a leading backslash seems to have no effect.

Any ideas on how I could solve this? I believe the fault lies in this line here:

`in = new FileInputStream("data/build_info.properties");`

## Code- Updated

#### Transitioned to Java Properties

```
String revision = "";

Properties defaultProps = new Properties();
FileInputStream in;
try {
    in = new FileInputStream("data/build_info.properties");
    defaultProps.load(in);
    in.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    
revision = "Version: " + defaultProps.getProperty("build.major.number") + "." +
defaultProps.getProperty("build.minor.number") + "    " +
"Revision: " + defaultProps.getProperty("build.revision.number");
```

#### ANT Jar Script

```
<target name="jar">
    <antcall target="clean" />
    <antcall target="compile" />

    <jar destfile="${dir.dist}/${name.jar}" basedir="." includes="${dir.lib}/*" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="emp.main.EmpowerView" />
        </manifest>
        <fileset dir="${dir.build}" includes="**/*" excludes="META-INF/*.SF" />
        <fileset dir="." includes="${dir.media}/*" />
        <fileset dir="." includes="${dir.data}/*" />
    </jar>
    <chmod file="${dir.dist}/${name.jar}" perm="+x" />

</target>
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you using regular expression instead of [`java.util.Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)?

Comment: Haha, because I was unaware of that functionality. Rest assured that I will make the transition soon.

Comment: Jolly-good then. You need to post newFile(), if that's where the problem is.

Comment: Edited to show most recent code and errors

Comment: where is `build_info.properties`?  In the Jar?  Outside of it?

Comment: It is in the JAR in the `data` directory. I have posted my JAR making ANT Script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to load a file inside of the Jar, then you need to use [`java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to load the file.  You can't point to a file that's in the Jar with `java.util.File`.  For an example on how to use it, see this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548791

Comment: Currently trying this, but the `Properties.load` expects an `InputStream` not a `FileInputStream`

Comment: @Peaches: `FileInputStream` is a subclass of `InputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you step through with the debugger?  I notice you have some System.out.println's - are they being printed when uncommented?

Regardless, I don't see how revision is null -- it could be an empty String due to an IOException, but not null.

Comment: When an IOException is called, the code sets `revision = e.getCause`

Comment: This means that the cause of the IOException was null.

Comment: Ah, so you are getting an IO exception - for some reason, that wasn't obvious to me in your original post. :)  
I agree with Jonah that you should use Properties

Comment: I have switched to using `Properties` but i am still suffering from a `FileNotFoundException`

Answer (score 0):

What happening here is as follows, the call to `newfile()` or `FileUtils.readLines()` is throwing an IOException.
This is being caught at :

```
} catch (IOException e) {
    revision = "" + e.getCause();
}
```

and is setting revision = the value of `e.getCause()` prefixed by an empty String.

`e.getCause()` is returning the text **null**, which leads me to believe that the exception is being thrown by `FileUtils.readLines()`.
Test this by changing `revision = "" + e.getCause();` to `revision = "XXX->" + e.getCause();`, after which I expect you'll find that the value of revision after the call is = "XXX->null".

The IOException with cause=null is being thrown because the file `data/build_info.properties` cannot be located.

So you need to check the value of your current working directory when you run this code, and ensure that `data/build_info.properties` can be resolved relative to that path.