# Is it possible to put resources file into JAR files?

Tags: java, web-applications, resources, jar, classpath

I have web application that runs on tomcat. I would like to put some resources in

```
resources.jar
```

e.g.

```
configuration.xml
```

But when I try:

```
  new File("/conf/configuration.xml")
```

it didn't found.

May be I should configure path in another way?

Comment: did you configured the jar in classpath of the application

Comment: possible duplicate of [load file within a jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548699/load-file-within-a-jar)

Comment: what you mean in classpath? This jar in webapps/mywebapplication/WEB-INF/lib. I think all jars in this folder are in classpath.

Comment: Have a look at the question I linked here, it does not exactly describe your problem, but will work for you as well (use the classloader).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running in a web application, you should use the `ContextClassLoader`:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("/conf/configuration.xml");
```

or

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/conf/configuration.xml");
```

The first one will return a `URL`, the second one an `InputStream`.