# jar file launched, image missing

Tags: java, jar, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [load file within a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548699/load-file-within-a-jar)

Finally, I made my jar file work almost correctly. Almost, because when I test it and launch just after creating jar file, a picture which is included in the archive appears. But when I move the jar file to any other directory and try to launch - I get an exception regarding missing picture (the application is still working though, but doesn't display that picture).

This is how it looks in my directory:

```
[aqv@voland Converter]$ ll
razem 112
-rw-rw-r--. 1 aqv aqv 51673 10-30 20:42 Converter.java
-rw-rw-r--. 1 aqv aqv    23 10-30 20:41 Converter.mf
-rw-rw-r--. 1 aqv aqv  1167 10-30 20:43 GBC.java
-rw-rw-r--. 1 aqv aqv  1023 10-30 20:58 ImagePanel.java
-rw-rw-r--. 1 aqv aqv 44729 10-30 20:35 programHelp.png
-rw-rw-r--. 1 aqv aqv  3713 10-30 20:43 SettingsManager.java
[aqv@voland Converter]$ 
[aqv@voland Converter]$
```

The picture file gets called from *ImagePanel*, *programHelp* is a string which is then passed to proper method:

```
public ImagePanel() {

    programHelp = "programHelp.png";

    try {
        helpImage = ImageIO.read(new File(programHelp));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are no directories specified, so I guess the main class should look for the image in the jar's main directory, shouldn't it?

I create the jar file in the following way (after compiling the files, of course):

```
[aqv@voland Converter]$ jar cvfm Converter.jar Converter.mf *.class *.png
[aqv@voland Converter]$
```

The picture file is visible inside the jar archive, among class files. My question: what is wrong with the image file placement in this case?

Comment: `new File(...)` only looks in the file system, not inside your jar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program is only working by coincidence - it is actually loading the PNG from *outside* the JAR. You could test this by temporarily renaming the image but keeping the JAR in the directory, if you like.

To load resources from within a JAR, you need to use one of the getResource() [methods of a Class object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29), rather than loading files directly.

You can still use `ImageIO` to load the data from the stream returned by `getResourceAsStream()`, for example. Something like the following:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("my.png");
helpImage = ImageIO.read(is);
```