# resource image not being included to jar upon build

Tags: java, image, jar, embedded-resource

I am currently using the following code segment to get the image for the interface.

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("./lib/logo.gif");

JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
lblNewLabel.setIcon(img);
lblNewLabel.setBounds(28, 65, 140, 100);
```

However, when i execute clean and build, the image does not appear when i execute the jar file. What seems to be the problem and where should I put the image file? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "However, when i execute clean and build, the image does not appear when i execute the jar file. What seems to be the problem and where should I put the image file?"

This is the reason you *don't* load from a file. You want to load it as an [**embedded resources**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) from your class path with a URL

Your image should be in a package somewhere in the `src` during development. When you build, the IDE with copy that image for you into the class path, and add it to the jar

[image]

Then to load from the class path in your code.

`Class.getResource(..)` return a URL, so you want to do this

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(MyClass.class.getResource("/images/logo.gif"));
```

Comment: Sorry to ask this kind of question, but what does Myclass and class stand for? so that i can adapt it

Comment: Your Class that has the code of the ImageIcon. `.class` just means the `Class` object `MyClass`, where `MyClass` is the class where the code is in `ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(..)`

Comment: Whatever your class name is, just replace `MyClass` with it

Answer (score 1):

In the code snippet you provided, the path to the image file is considered to be on the file system (the constructor of class [ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.lang.String%29) takes a file name as an argument). If you want to load a file (or an image) from the jar itself, you need to use [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548699/load-file-within-a-jar) question.