# Unable to load XSL file from JAR file

Tags: java, xslt, jar

I have a java file which uses XSL file to perform transformation. 
Code used is:

> FileInputStream inXLSFile = new FileInputStream("ListApi.xsl");
>     TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
>     StreamSource xslStream = new StreamSource(inXLSFile);
>   After this a jar file is generated. from the jar file I am not able to use the XSL. It says 'File not found'. Please give pointers.

Answer (score 4):

change

```
FileInputStream inXLSFile = new FileInputStream("ListApi.xsl");
```

to

```
InputStream inXLSFile = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("ListApi.xsl");
```

for more information read about [how do I load a file from a jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548699/load-file-within-a-jar)

Comment: this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("ListApi.xsl") returns a InputStream and it cannot be used in creating a new FileInputStream object. Kindly help me to out with some other option.

Comment: Actually i need to do some transformation using this XSL. If its InputStream then my tranfromFactory is throwing a error. Its expecting FileInputStream.Code used is:             TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
   StreamSource xslStream = new StreamSource(inXLSFile);

   Transformer transformer;
   transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslStream);

Comment: Which StreamSource do use use? Look at the documentation. StreamSource has a constructor that takes a InputStream: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html#StreamSource%28java.io.InputStream%29

Comment: Yes. It works fine. the path where XSL resides was wrong. Corrected the same. Thank you Markus! Have a nice day.

Comment: In that case (XSL files in the JAR), how can we import others XSL files from the first one (all XSL files are in the same jars)
Like <xsl:import href="??/liens.xsl"