# Call Property file from a jar included in my project

Tags: java, jar, properties-file

I´ve included a jar (I built it: **MyJar.jar**) that i use to authenticate, in that jar I have to read some properties that I have in a package (e.g com.myproject.properties) inside a property file of my project.

I have a method in **MyJar.jar** which receive the name of the property and the path for the property file something like this:

```
public String getValueOfProperty(String property,String pathToPropertyFile){

    BasicTextEncryptor encryptor = new BasicTextEncryptor();
         Properties props = new EncryptableProperties(encryptor);
         props.load(new FileInputStream(pathToPropertyFile));
         ....
}
```

I got the following error: System can't find the specified path

The path is: **com/myproject/properties/conf.properties**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the properties file packed within the jar? If so, you will have to load it differently.

Comment: It is in a package in the project i've included the jar @user2494817

Comment: Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548699/load-file-within-a-jar

Comment: It does not have to be within the jar, It is in a package **com.myproject.properties** in a new project where i have included the jar file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,

This is what i Used:

The path the method receives is something like this: **/sv/com/myproject/configuration/file.properties**,

This method will search with relative path

```
 public String decryptVar(String var,String PathPropertyFile) throws Exception{

    try {
         BasicTextEncryptor encryptor = new BasicTextEncryptor();
         Properties props = new EncryptableProperties(encryptor);
         InputStream fis = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(PathPropertyFile);
         props.load(fis);
         encryptor.setPassword(props.getProperty("PROPERTY_IN_FILE")); 
         return props.getProperty(var);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }   

}
```

Implementing: **JASYPTH**