# How to get the path of a file relative to the .jar root?

Tags: java, file, spring-boot, path, relative-path

My directory structure inside the compiled jar looks like this (Spring Boot Structure):

```
 - BOOT-INF
   - classes
      - ...
      - templates
         - Java_Template.ftl
    - lib
      - ...
 - org
   - ...
 - META-INF
   - ...
```

and I need to get the path of Java_Template.ftl relative to the .jar root (`BOOT-INF\classes\templates\Java_template.ftl`) as a String, but I don't want to hardcode the `BOOT-INF\classes\` part, so how do I get it?

I've tried `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("templates/Java_template.ftl").toString()`
but it returns the path relative to C: (or some other drive), which is not what I need.

My required result: `BOOT-INF\classes\` 
Or: `BOOT-INF\classes\templates\Java_template.ftl`

Comment: Duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47537098/error-reading-file-in-a-jar/47537218#47537218

Comment: `YourClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();`

Comment: @elysrivero99 What am I supposed to do with an InputStream? I need a String!

Comment: @notyou `The method getLoc‌​ation() is undefined for the type CodeSource` :( Nevermind, you just messed up your c somehow, it was `99 226 128 140 226 128 139` in decimal

Comment: @notyou It doesn't work, it returns `file:/C:/maven-repository/de/abc/sbk/def/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/def-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/`. It may only have the `BOOT-INF/classes!/` part though, preferably without the exlamation marks.

Comment: Just trying to help - it worked for me, albeit in a different scenario - that's why I added as a comment, and not an answer.

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox you could convert de inputStream into a String ¬¬ ... For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string

Comment: @elysrivero99 You got me wrong. I need the path of the file relative to the jar root (as a String). I neither need the path of the file relative to the drive, **nor the content of the file**.